# In emacs, what does "Terminal 7 is locked, cannot read from it" mean?

Tags: emacs, terminal

When using emacs, I occasionally get the error `Terminal 7 is locked, cannot read from it`. What does this error mean?

Currently, I am receiving the error while I try to connect to an IRC server using `erc`, but I have received it before, though I don't remember for what. When it happened before, I was able to retry and eventually it worked, but now I get the same error every time.

I'm running a server session with `emacs --daemon` and have connected various clients with `emacsclient -t`.

I have searched for this online, but the only thing I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000710/how-do-i-control-emacs-from-a-terminal). Aside from not being the exact question I have, it has no accepted answer. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that some Elisp code is trying to read from the minibuffer (for example) while in the middle of some other command in another "terminal" (e.g. another tty).  "In the middle" here means for example that you're using a minibuffer in that other terminal, or that you've hit a prefix key.

I suggest you try to come up with a reproducible way to trigger this error and then send it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was going to restart emacs to try again, but after I had closed everything down (right before I would run `M-x kill-emacs`), I tried connecting again. This time it worked. Next time I have the error I will try to see if I can figure out what causes it.